# Does converting a float column to a bigint column result in a whole table copy in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, bigint

we want to convert in a huge (100 Mio. rows) SQL Server table one column from FLOAT(8) to BIGINT. We do not care about the floating points and losing precision.

Since I do not own a SQL Server but are using mysql locally I am wondering if this operation results in a whole table copy as it would do with my database!? On the other hand I read that this would be an implicit conversion and thus it would be a matter of seconds instead of hours.

Instead of setting up a SQL Server and reproducing it locally which could take pretty much time I would like to ask you if the answer is a simple "yes, it does a table copy", or "float8 to bigint, no it's not a problem".

Thx for your help!

Comment: will you be doing the conversion via code, or via ssms's ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to do this one in place.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
c float,
d int,
v varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,1,'')


alter table T alter column c bigint

SELECT  sc.name, sipc.leaf_offset, sipc.max_inrow_length
FROM    sys.partitions sp
        JOIN sys.system_internals_partition_columns sipc
             ON sp.partition_id = sipc.partition_id
     left   JOIN sys.columns sc
             ON sc.column_id = sipc.partition_column_id AND sc.object_id = sp.object_id
WHERE   sp.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T') 

DROP TABLE T
```

Returns

```
name leaf_offset max_inrow_length
---- ----------- ----------------
NULL 4           8
d    12          4
v    -1          10
c    4           8
```

The old `float` column is still visible but the `bigint` column has just taken over the slot. It will need to update every record of course though to make this change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was exactly the information i needed!

Comment: Do you know since which version this is done in situ? We reproduced this behavior with MSSQL 2008, but are still officially supporting MSSQL 2000. If this is a problem there we still got a problem.